# text options for seo-minded web developer

Tags: text, fonts, seo, cufon

I've been asked by a client if i could jazz up their tagline on their website i'm developing/designing. I've thought about the options and want to stay as SEO minded as i can but i'm struggling to think of a way i could strike a balance between having a really smart, anti-aliased looking heading at the top of their site under the logo but have it searchable/crawlable by the big G (google). Sifr? Cufon? Images? What do people recommend in terms of SEO and visual niceties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cufon only works with freeware fonts and most fonts are not freeware. sIFR is the best bet for cross browser compatibility. If you arent supporting older browsers, you should definitely go with the @font-face CSS attribute. Web font services like TypeKit, Font Squirrel, or the free Google Font Library are good bets.

Comment: Clarification: Cufon works with ALL fonts, but it is illegal to use with licensed fonts.... unless you live in China or Nigeria or something like that :)